# entered data will not be displayed in textfield react native

Tags: react-native

user entered data data will not be displayed in react native material textfield

```
this.state = {
    userName: ''

}


render() {
    let { userName } = this.state;

    return (

        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>

            <TextField style={{ color: 'black', marginLeft: windowSize.width / 1.4, color: 'red' }}
                label='Phone number'
                textColor={'red'}
                value={userName}
                labelHeight={40}
                labelPadding={1}
                Bottom padding={8}
                onChangeText={(userName) => this.setState({ userName })}
            />
```

Comment: It will not show they type as well or once value being entered?

Comment: can you explain

Comment: Once user finish typing then it will not show or while typying you will not able to see ....

Comment: while typing i will not able to see